# .htaccess RewriteCond REQUEST_URI Dynamic SEO Generated URIs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic, seo

Ok my eyes and fingers are bleeding now trying to get this stuff to work.  Here is a couple examples of incoming URIs I want to test in my .htaccess file.

```
abc.com
abc.com/en
abc.com/zh-cn/
abc.com/fr/page1
abc.com/fr/page2/page3
abc.com/fr/page2/page3/
abc.com/fr/page2/page3.html
```

The first dir needs to be a UTF-8 language code between 2 and 5 characters long, with or without a / at the end.  This is what I currently use to test for this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(([a-z]{2})(-[a-z]{2})?)
```

The second dir and on can just be lumped together and cleaned later on in my code.  Here is the full RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(([a-z]{2})(-[a-z]{2})?)([a-z0-9-\./]*)$ [NC]
```

I'm getting a 403 error from this.  Any one know what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks a ton,

Vince

Comment: Where is your actual rule?

Comment: The RewriteRule isn't my problem, I know the 403 error is being generated on the RewriteCond line but here it is.
RewriteRule ^(([a-z]{2})(-[a-z]{2})?)([a-z0-9-\./]*) /index.php?lng=$1&tpl=$4 [QSA,L,NC]

Comment: _“Any one know what I'm doing wrong here?”_ – ask someone who should know: your server. That’s what log files are for. (If the error reason does not become clear from access/error log alone, enable rewrite log as well on your test machine.)

Comment: It is impossible for a `RewriteCond` directive to generate a 403 Forbidden response, since it doesn't do anything except determine whether the immediately following rule is eligible to be applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution that I actaully ended up using.

URI examples that I may need to pars:

```
abc.com/en
abc.com/zh-cn/
abc.com/fr/page1
abc.com/ru/dir1/page2
abc.com/jp/dir1/page2/
abc.com/es-mx/dir1/dir2/page3.html
```

The RewriteRule I ended up using:

```
RewriteRule ^(([a-z]{2})(-[a-z]{2})?)(/([a-z0-9-\./]*))?$ /index.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
```